# Show that $X= \ker((u-\lambda)^p) \oplus (u-\lambda)^p(X)$ if $u$ is compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, operator-theory, compact-operators

Consider the following theorem in Murphy's book "C*-algebras and operator theory"

[image: ker]

Can someone explain why the marked lines are true? I think this must be a matter of pure linear algebra but I can't find out the specifics. I.e. my question, why is

$$X= \ker((u-\lambda)^p) + (u-\lambda)^p(X)$$Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from dimensional reasons. You have that the kernel and the image are linearly independent and that the complement of the image has dimension of the defect, which is the same dimension as the kernel.

More concretely, since $\ker(u-\lambda)^p$ and $(u-\lambda)^p(X)$ are disjoint you have that the map
$$\ker(u-\lambda)^p\to X/(u-\lambda)^p(X)$$
is injective, but this is an injective map between vector spaces of the same dimension, hence a vectors space isomorphism. Thus $\ker(u-\lambda)^p$ is a complement of $(u-\lambda)^p(X)$.

Comment: How does the isomorphism $\ker(u-\lambda)^p \cong X/(u-\lambda)^p(X)$ imply that we have the direct sum decomposition? I want this as in inner direct sum, not an outer one.

Comment: The situation is of this form: $V, W\subseteq X$ are two sub-spaces, denote with $p: X\to X/V$ the quotient map and assume that $p\lvert_W : W\to X/V$ is a vectorspace isomorphism. It then follows that $V$ is a complement to $W$. It is clear that $V\cap W=\{0\}$ is implied by that, but also if there is some $x\in X$ with $x\notin V+W$ then $p(x)$ cannot have a pre-image in $V$ (else you could correct this pre-image by an element of $W$ to get $x$) contradicting the assumed isomorphism. The important part is that here the isomorphism is given by the restriction of the quotient map.

Comment: I see it now! Thanks!

Comment: Suuuuuuper late reply, but this also just follows from theorem $1.4.8$.  Since $(u-\lambda)$ is fredholm (from condition 1) it follows by theorem $1.4.8$ that $(u-\lambda)^p$ is fredholm with index equal to $\text{ind}(u-\lambda)^p = p \: \text{ind}(u-\lambda) = p(0)=0$.